# How to capture a signal in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

How I can send s signal from one qml component to another?

Below is an example:

```
Rectangle {
    id: main
    width: 360; height: 360
    signal clicked()

    Text {
        id: testStr
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World"
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: { Qt.quit(); }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: clicked()
    onClicked:  testStr.text = "Demo"
}
```

How do I capture the signal in other Component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `connect()` method of component's signals (signals themselves are objects).

```
function clickHandler() {
    console.log('main clicked')
}
Component.onCompleted: {
    main.clicked.connect(clickHandler)
}
```

See http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmlevents.html

Comment: Thank you. Can it explain that the signal(onXXXXX) is only used in itself , if want to be captured in other , use Connecet?

Comment: Yes, if you declare an instance of a component in your qml file you can assign code to pre-defined onXxx slot of that component. It's already connected, you just bind an expression to it. If you want to connect a signal with slot of another instance or a function, you have to use `connect` method.

Answer (score 9):

In the other object, you simply add a `on` word followed by the signal name.  EG:

```
Rectangle {
  YourQmlObject {
    onClicked: { ... }
  }
}
```

(clicked is somewhat a confusing signal name because it's common.  But if you had called your signal `orange`, you'd make the binding `onOrange:`)

Comment: thanks for your help. If there are lots of 'YourQmlObject' , then will i write onClicked: { ... } in each Component ?  There are other way ?

Comment: The signals will propegate up, so you could put your "lots" into a single container `AllMyQmlObjects` that is a long list of your objects, and put the `onClicked:` handler in whatever file eventually contains the `AllMyQmlObjects`.

Answer (score 5):

you can use QML connection element

```
 Connections {
 target: yourQmlObject 
 onClicked: foo(...)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

QML

```
Button{
  id: btn_add_pq
  text: "Add"
  onClicked: {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("add_pq.qml")
    var dialog    = component.createObject(root)
    dialog.open()

    dialog.accepted.connect(function(){
      console.log("ID     :" + window.in_id)
      console.log("Name   :" + window.in_name)
      console.log("Comment:" + window.in_comment)
    })
  }
}
```

add_pq.qml

```
Dialog {
  id:dialog
  ...
  property alias in_id: txtID.text
  property alias in_comment: txtComment.text
  property alias in_name: txtName.text
  ...
  contentItem: GridLayout{
    ...
    TextField{
      id: txtComment
      Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }
    Button{
      Layout.columnSpan: 2
      text: "Add"
      Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
      onClicked: {
        dialog.click(StandardButton.Save)
      }
    }
  }
```